# Spring Boot JPA not updating MySQL database after PUT request

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have made a spring boot application connected to an angular front end. When the user enters a value into attendance id and hits submit on the form, this calls a method that updates the current value  in the database using a HTTP PUT request.

However, the value is not being update despite break points showing the new value is being received and updated.

I am new to spring boot so any help is appreciated.

```
     package com.example.demo.Attendance;

    import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import com.example.demo.AttendancePK.AttendancePK;
import com.example.demo.AttendanceType.AttendanceType;
import com.example.demo.LessonRun.LessonRun;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

    @Transactional
    @Entity
    public class Attendance {

        @EmbeddedId
        private AttendancePK id;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="attendance_type", insertable = false, updatable=false)
        private AttendanceType attendanceType;


        @ManyToOne
        @JsonIgnore
        @JoinColumn(name="lesson_run_id", insertable = false, updatable=false)
        private LessonRun lessonRun;


        public LessonRun getLessonRun() {
            return lessonRun;
        }

        public void setLessonRun(LessonRun lessonRun) {
            this.lessonRun = lessonRun;
        }

        public AttendanceType getAttendanceType() {
            return attendanceType;
        }

        public void setAttendanceType(AttendanceType attendanceType) {
            this.attendanceType = attendanceType;
        }


        public Attendance(AttendancePK id, AttendanceType attendanceType, LessonRun lessonRun) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.attendanceType = attendanceType;
            this.lessonRun = lessonRun;
        }


        public Attendance() {

        }

        public AttendancePK getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(AttendancePK id) {
            this.id = id;
        }



    }
```

My controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/attendance/{attendanceId}/student/{studentId}/lessonrun/{lessonRunId}",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void updateAttendance(@PathVariable int attendanceId, @PathVariable int studentId, @PathVariable int lessonRunId, @RequestBody int attendanceTypeId) {
        AttendancePK id = new AttendancePK(attendanceId, studentId,lessonRunId);
        Attendance attendanceInDB =  attendanceService.getAttendancebyId(id);
//      attendanceInDB.setAttendanceType(int.getAttendanceType());
        attendanceService.updateAttendance(attendanceInDB, attendanceTypeId);
    }
```

My Service

```
   package com.example.demo.Attendance;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.AttendancePK.AttendancePK;
import com.example.demo.AttendanceType.AttendanceType;
import com.example.demo.AttendanceType.AttendanceTypeRepository;

@Service
public class AttendanceService {

    @Autowired
    private AttendanceRepository attendanceRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AttendanceTypeRepository attendanceTypeRepository;

    public List<Attendance> getAllAttendanceRecs() {
        List<Attendance> attendanceList = new ArrayList<>();
        attendanceRepository.findAll().forEach(attendanceList::add);
        return attendanceList;
    }

    public Attendance getAttendancebyId(AttendancePK id) {
        Optional<Attendance> optionalAttendance = attendanceRepository.findById(id);
        if (optionalAttendance.isPresent()) {
            return optionalAttendance.get();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void updateAttendance(Attendance attendanceInDB, int attendanceTypeId) {
        Optional<AttendanceType> attendanceType = attendanceTypeRepository.findById(attendanceTypeId);
        if (attendanceType.isPresent()) {
            attendanceInDB.setAttendanceType(attendanceType.get());
            attendanceRepository.save(attendanceInDB);
        }

    }
}
```

[the breakpoint results show the value is updated shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJen3.png)

but MySQL database doesn't reflect this

Comment: Use @Transactional on your service class

Comment: @GovindParashar I have but still no luck. the database remains the same

Comment: There is no transaction, no transaction nothing persisted into the database.

Comment: @M.Deinum I stated I have include this but no luck. thanks

Comment: You haven't. The `@Transactional` on your entity is useless. It should be on the transactional boundary, your service. So the fact tha tyou have an annotation doesn't mean it works or is it the proper place.